# Group by Date -Month -Day Hour and Time Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Group by Date -Month -Day Hour and Time Query**

I would like to group by Rundate and then JobDateStamp by yy/mm/dd hh:mm 
no seconds

**Results**

```
[RunDate]          [count]  
12/11/2014 21:00     3  
13/11/2014 21:00     1
```

3 lots of jobs were run on 12/11/2014 (3 date and time)
1 lots of jobs were run on 13/11/2014 (1 date and time)

```
**create table tbl_tasks**  

(  
Rundate datetime,  
JobDateStamp datetime,  
Runs int  
)  

insert into tbl_tasks values   
('2014-11-13 21:00:46.393','2014-11-13 21:36:27.393',1),  
('2014-11-13 21:00:46.393','2014-11-13 21:36:25.393',1),  
('2014-11-13 21:00:46.393','2014-11-13 21:36:24.393',1),  
('2014-11-12 21:00:47.000','2014-11-13 14:14:46.393',1),  
('2014-11-12 21:00:47.000','2014-11-13 14:12:46.393',1),  
('2014-11-12 21:00:47.000','2014-11-12 21:04:43.393',1),  
('2014-11-12 21:00:47.000','2014-11-12 21:04:41.393',1)
```

**This data is a result of a query and next step is to group by**
**yy/mm/dd hh:mm**

Rundate                    JobDateStamp        Runs
2014-11-13 21:00:46.393   2014-11-13 21:36:27.393   1
2014-11-13 21:00:46.393   2014-11-13 21:36:25.393   1
2014-11-13 21:00:46.393   2014-11-13 21:36:24.393   1
2014-11-12 21:00:47.000   2014-11-13 14:14:46.393   1
2014-11-12 21:00:47.000   2014-11-13 14:12:46.393   1
2014-11-12 21:00:47.000   2014-11-12 21:04:43.393   1
2014-11-12 21:00:47.000   2014-11-12 21:04:41.393   1

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL 2008 have tried dateadd but as below i get count of 7

Comment: @winchmore, can you try my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by converting time to minutes and using `count(distinct .. )`

As you need further filter by jobdatestamp, need to use it in count

```
SELECT dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, rundate), 0) , 
       count( distinct dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, JobDateStamp), 0))
FROM tbl_tasks
GROUP by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, rundate), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just truncate the datetime to the previous minute and group by that value:

```
select 
    dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Rundate ), 0) RunDate,
    COUNT(*) Count
FROM tbl_tasks  
GROUP BY dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, Rundate ), 0)
```

Comment: thanks have tried dateadd but get same may be needs a pivot count?

Comment: 2014-11-12 21:00   4    
2014-11-13 21:00          3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012`, you can also make some use of the `Format` to group on:

```
Select  Rundate, Count(*) Count
From
(
    Select  Format(Rundate, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm') Rundate, JobDateStamp, Runs
    From    tbl_tasks
)A
Group By Rundate
```

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 4
'Format' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Ah, just noticed you're using `Sql Server 2008`.  Yeah, this method won't work then.